# What should I do if my spring-boot service throws checked exception?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here's the code from my spring boot service class:

```
@Service
public class AmazonClient {

    @Override
    public String uploadFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        String fileUrl = "";
            File file = convertMultiPartToFile(multipartFile);
            String fileName = generateFileName(multipartFile);
            fileUrl = endpointUrl + "/" + bucketName + "/" + fileName;
            uploadFileTos3bucket(fileName, file);
            file.delete();
        return fileUrl;
    }

    private File convertMultiPartToFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        return convFile;
    }
...
```

So I need to handle call to `convertMultiPartToFile(MultipartFile file)` method because it throws `IOException`. If I want to use exception handler provided by spring what is the best way to manage the situation? Should I use `throws` clause?

Comment: catch the checked exception in uploadFile() and throw a runtime exception with user understandable message.

Comment: Catch the exception and rethrow as a proper `RuntimeException` subclass.